# Where is the fiscal resident of international students receiving scholarship

Tags: germany, tax-residency, student, scholarship, turkey

I am a citizen of Turkey, and I am studying in Germany while receiving a scholarship from the German government.

Where is my fiscal residence?, i.e where is my tax-residency?

**Edit:**

I have no other income other than the scholarship, which is not taxed by Germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a tax resident of Germany (the legal term being *"unbeschränkt steuerpflichtig"*) if you have a residence in Germany or spend most of your time in Germany ([§1 EStG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/estg/__1.html)).

In order to prevent people from being taxed by both Turkey and Germany, there is a treaty between Germany and Turkey with the short and sweet name *["Agreement
between the Federal Republic of Germany and the Republic of Turkey for the Avoidance of Double Taxation and of Tax Evasion with respect to taxes on Income"](https://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Content/DE/Standardartikel/Themen/Steuern/Internationales_Steuerrecht/Staatenbezogene_Informationen/Laender_A_Z/Tuerkei/2012-05-30-Tuerkei-Abkommen-DBA-Gesetz.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=2)* which says:

> he shall be deemed to be a resident only of the State in which he has
>   a permanent home available to him; if he has a permanent home
>   available to him in both States, he shall be deemed to be a resident
>   only of the State with which his personal and economic relations are
>   closer (centre of vital interests);

So if you live in Germany, you are a German tax resident. If you have both a home in Germany and in Turkey, so it's unclear where you live, you are a tax resident in the country where most of your personal and economic life takes place. And because your main and only occupation is being a student in Germany, that would be Germany.

As long as you are not paying income taxes, there is no point in filing your taxes. If you *do* pay income taxes, then you might not actually be required to file taxes, but it is usually stupid to not do it, because a regular salaryperson has practically always things they can deduct in order to receive some money back.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Philip. You perfectly answered my question, but could you give an example about the thing you mentioned in your last paragraph?

Comment: @onurcanbektas *How* to do your taxes in Germany isn't really part of your original question. So if you have any questions about that, I would recommend you to ask a new question.

Comment: See my new question: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125825/how-much-do-i-need-to-pay-as-taxes-for-this-investment-how-to-calculate-it