# How much do I need to pay as taxes for this investment? How to calculate it?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, germany

I am relatively new to both investing and doing your taxes in Germany. I have read many articles, none of which were official documents because I couldn't find them (also I don't know German). But I still do not understand how to do my taxes and how much need pay.

How much tax do I have to pay for capital gains? Could you explain the calculations in a clear example?

For example, let say I bought an ETF which is paying dividends quarterly, and it doubled its price by the end of the fiscal year (say the price was 100Euros, and it paid 10Euros dividend).

---

Also, how can I verify that the tax I paid was correct? For example, if I pay fewer taxes than what I would need to, what happens?

Comment: So, to clarify, the price of the ETF has risen from €100 to €200, and it's also paid €40 in dividends, meaning you have total gains of €140?

Comment: @TannerSwett Yes. (if you like, you can use another example too)

Answer (score 1):

> how can I verify that the tax I paid was correct?

Well, I see only two ways here:

- learn German and read the tax law

  - you can also hire a tax advisor, but you'll anyways stay personally liable for paying the correct taxes.
- Take everything you can remotely imagine to be relevant to your tax office's service desk and ask them whether you paid the taxes correctly and/or what declarations you need to file. They'll refuse to give tax *advise* but they'll confirm if the taxes were paid correctly and they'll tell you what forms to submit.

---

The ETF: here the calculation is somewhat complex, but [here is a web site that explains and does example calculations (in German, though)](https://www.justetf.com/de/news/etf/etf-und-steuern-das-neue-investmentsteuergesetz-ab-2018.html)