# why is it always advisable to file taxes at the end of the fiscal year?

Tags: taxes, germany, scholarship

For a student living in Germany and having only income a tax-free scholarship, why is it always advisable to file taxes at the end of the fiscal year, [as suggested by this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/125822/66087)

Comment: The linked answer suggests: `because a regular salaryperson has practically always things they can deduct`

Comment: @BernhardDöbler as I have asked in the comments of the same answer, `such as ?`

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_Germany#Deductions) has some examples. If you need more personalized advice, you're better off talking to a tax preparer.